# How to ground a laptop which does not have an earth pin

Tags: laptop, audio, power, microphone

I have a laptop which does not have an earth pin on its plug. Because of this whenever I try to record audio using an external microphone there is a terrible buzzing sound.

How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you can obtain a grounding cord for the laptop and connect it to a metal interface on the laptop, such as the USB port.
Below is a grounding cable from Less EMF. Although you could make your own grounding cable, this is a hard-to-beat price. This is a special cable under $10 where only the grounding wire will be used-- the hot and neutral wires should not be present, or if they are, they should not be plugged in. One end has the ground plug. In some cases, the hot and neutral pins are removed from the plug. In other cases, the hot and neutral pins are still present in the plug, but are not wired past the plug of the cable. In the example below from Less EMF, there is only one thin wire coming out of the head.
[image]
The metal ring on the other side of the plug can be inserted snugly in the upper portion of the USB port, although it is a little hard to fit in. For easier insertion, you can remove the ring terminal and crimp on a spade terminal instead with the help of a wire stripper and crimper for ease of insertion.
[image]
You can now insert the plug into the outlet and insert the spade terminal into the USB interface of your computer shown below. You can squeeze it on the top part of the USB interface, so that it is fit snugly and touched to the metal of the USB interface. If you run out of USB ports as a result, you can connect the metal terminal to a USB hub which is connected to the computer.
[image]
source:[How to Ground a Laptop](http://www.emfwise.com/how-to-ground-appliances.php)

Answer (score 0):

Simply unplug your laptop and let it run on battery and do the recording. This works on my laptop but only for a short time since the battery is old. Maybe a better solution but this should be good for laptops with batteries that last long.

I still do not know how to fix the problem without unplugging the power. I have another laptop with an integrated microphone and earth pin and it does not have a buzzing sound while plugged in since it has the earth pin

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a ground wire from my mic to the wall earth. Just not sure if that's safe for the laptop, but it sure does get rid of my problem.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRJtP.jpg]